# Undefined method logger while attempting to send mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am receiving the following error when I try to send mail using a mailer.  I have a form that allows the user to fill in name, email, and message.  Clicking the submit button posts to the send_mail action of the ContactsController.

```
[2012-03-11 14:31:00] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `logger' for ActionMailer::Base:Class
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-3.2.2/lib/action_mailer/log_subscriber.rb:17:in `logger
'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/template.rb:285:in `to_proc'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:76:in `map'

        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:76:in `flus
hable_loggers'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:84:in `flus
h_all!'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:28:in `call_app'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in
`call'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb
:72:in `call'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `cal
l'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:55
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        C:/dev/tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
        script/rails:6:in `require'
        script/rails:6
```

My controller looks like:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def mail

    end

  def send_mail
    ContactMailer.email(params[:email], params[:name], params[:message]).deliver
  end
end
```

My mailer looks like:

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "<from>"

  def email(email, name, message)
    @message = message
    mail(:to => "<email>", :subject => "<message>" + name, :from => email)
  end
end
```

Comment: I took a look at development.log and found this:

NameError (uninitialized constant Mail::TestMailer):
  app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:1
  app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:7:in `send_mail'

Another thing to note is that I am doing almost the same exact thing in a different project and it works.  This must be a configuration problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that there was a class overriding mail in the project.  Incase anyone ever runs into this same issue just delete or rename the mail class/model.